# Unable to find constructor when using varargs with new class

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I got a hibernate exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

My query is `"Select new example.ReportField(r.memberName, r.address) from Member r"`

```
public class ReportField {

    public List<String> fieldValueList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ReportField(Object... fields) {
        System.out.println("-----ReportField------");
        if (fields != null) {
            for (Object field : fields) {
                String fieldStr = field.toString();
                String[] temp = fieldStr.split(":");
                System.out.println("temp.length = " + temp.length);
                if (temp != null && temp.length == 2
                        && "uuid".equals(temp[0].toLowerCase())) {
                    fieldValueList.add(SysUtil.getNodeByUUID(temp[1]));
                } else {
                    fieldValueList.add(fieldStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> getFieldValueList() {
        return fieldValueList;
    }

    public void setFieldValueList(List<String> fieldValueList) {
        this.fieldValueList = fieldValueList;
    }
}
```

If I change the constructor to

```
public ReportField(String memberName, String memberAddress) and it works
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late but *Multiple SELECT Expressions* can be used for solving this problem as long as you use **JPA 2**.

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(
  "SELECT r.memberName, r.address FROM Member r", Object[].class);

List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();

List<ReportField> fields = new ArrayList<ReportField>(); // Use your favorite class instead of ArrayList if necessary
for (Object[] result : results) {
    fields.add(new ReportField(result));
}
```

Alternatively, you could concatenate all your fields and then pass the resulting string to your constructor.

You could also generate on the fly a new class (use [Javassist](http://www.javassist.org)) and then pass this class to Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just the way hibernate is determining which constructors are available, but rather than plumbing the depths of hibernate code to figure out why, you could just "move on" and work around it like this:

```
public ReportField(Object... fields) {
    if (fields.length == 2) {
        init(fields[0], fields[1]);
        return;
    }
    // current code
}

public ReportField(String memberName, String memberAddress) {
    init(memberName, memberAddress);
}

private void init(String memberName, String memberAddress) {
    // whatever you need to do here
}
```

Incidentally, a varargs parameter is never `null` (but it may be an array of size zero) when called normally, so the null check may not be required.

Comment: My Sql is dynamic, it could pass two fields or three fields to constructor, such as "Select new example.ReportField(r.memberName, r.address, r.phoneNumber) from Member r"